# Drupal 8 password retention

Tags: 8, security

I am currently reviewing Drupal 8's security features and was wondering about how Drupal stores user passwords. I know Drupal uses salted hashes to store the password in the database, but does Drupal also store a user's previously used passwords so that they can't reuse them again? If it does, does that list have a hard limit to it (i.e. does it only store the last twenty used passwords before recycling the list)?

I am only interested in the out of the box experience with Drupal 8. I know there are modules that you can use to add extra functionality/security to user passwords but that isn't part of this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box, Drupal only stores the salted hash for the current password. No previous passwords are stored without the help of a contrib module such as [Password Policy](https://www.drupal.org/project/password_policy).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a the [Guardr distribution](https://www.drupal.org/project/guardr) it has all of the security modules already integrated and configured.

Even if you don't use it, they do a good job of pointing out the security modules available.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was unaware of this distribution.